# recursively delete all files except some especific types

Tags: bash

I want to recursively delete all files in some folders except those who have .gz extension. Normally I use

```
find /thepath -name "foo" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

to recursively delete all folders named "foo" in the /thepath. But now I wan to add an exclusion option. How that is possible?

For example, the folder structure looks like

```
 .hiddenfolder
 .hiddenfolder/bin.so
 arc.tar.gz
 note.txt
 sample
```

So I want to delete everything but keep `arc.tar.gz`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Find and delete all files under /thepath except with name matching *.gz:

```
# First check with ls -l
find /thepath -type f ! -name '*.gz' -print0 | xargs -0 ls -l

# Ok: delete
find /thepath -type f ! -name '*.gz' -print0 | xargs -0 rm -vf
```

Oh, and to delete all empty left-over directories:

```
find /thepath -type d -empty -print0 | xargs -0 rmdir -v
```

Comment: For those wandering around and stumbling on this reply, there is also the `-delete` option for GNU `find` utility that IMHO is convenient to use. I like that @grebneke added the last line where he checks for empty directories.

Comment: I would probably use `-exec` to list or delete the files... Most versions support ending it with a `+` rather than `\;` to pass multiple arguments. Also `-empty` is not portable to Solaris (
I usually simply try rmdir and let it spam errors for non-empty directories...)

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
find /thepath -name "foo" ! -name "*.gz" -print0
```

should produce the correct list of filenames, but check before piping the output to your `xargs` command to perform the actual deletions.

Comment: I used `find . -name "*" ! -name "*.gz" -print0` but it only prints the directory content

Comment: Just pipe it to xargs the way you did before. I think @chepner left that out to prevent people from accidentally their files with a copy & paste

Comment: yes that is right but grebneke's solution was more convenient by truly adding -type f. Cheers